# Background logcat with filter

Tags: crashes, logging, background-process

I have an app which seems to crash sometimes but of course not at that time when I have it connected to my PC and run logcat.

Is there a good method of grepping logcat in background (best would be filter by app but filter by text would already be helpful) and write the logfile to SD card for later inspection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a logcat app that writes the log to your sd card. Depending on the Android version on your device, that might require root permissions: latest with Android 4.2 "normal apps" only can see their own log. Checkout my list for [Logcat & Co.](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_logcat) for possible candidates. I know that e.g. [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rs.pedjaapps.alogcatroot.app) has the feature I've described. It also has filtering capabilities. Same applies to several other candidates of the linked list.

Comment: Thanks. root is no problem for me. But are you sure that aLogCat has this feature? It displays the logs but I don't see a settings where the logs are stored continuously in background. (To my understanding, the log uses a ring buffer). I also tried others but I could not find anything. Do I misunderstand the concept?

Comment: Ringbuffer is correct. And it lists "save logs" amongst its features. If you cannot figure out how to do it with that app, take a look at [Logcat Extreme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=scd.lcex), which praises itself as "Logcat recorder (even when in background)". The recording button of that one can hardly be missed :)